# magento rewrites to a second controller action

Tags: magento, url-rewriting

I am working on a magento module for to display a manufacturer list of motorcycles from a category.  This is separate to the cart and core magento functionality.  I am porting our current site over to magento so using this module to display our manufacturer motorbikes.

When a user clicks on the manufacturer they want the first rewrite takes them to the indexAction in the brandController which seems to work fine.

```
<rewrite>
        <phm_newbikes_brand_view>
            <complete />
            <from>#^/bikes/([A-Za-z]+).html#</from>
            <to>/bikes/brand/index/manufacturer/$1/</to>
        </phm_newbikes_brand_view>

        <!-- 
        <phm_newbikes_category_view>
            <complete />
            <from>#^/bikes/([A-Za-z]+)/([A-Za-z]+).html#</from>
            <to>/bikes/brand/category/manufacturer/$1/cat/$2/</to>
        </phm_newbikes_category_view>
         -->
</rewrite>
```

So when a user clicks on a category after landing on a manufacturer page they would be directed to the categoryAction in the BrandController but all I am getting is a 404 error.

Can anyone point me in the right direction of how to achieve this please?

Many thanks in advance.
Graham

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer to the question lay in the fact that the file I was trying to navigate to actually held a character that I had not allowed for in the rewrite rule.  Adding it to the rewrite fixed the issue.

Cheers
Graham